# Redefining the Word Character Class in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need to change the behavior of the `\w` character class in Perl. I would like it to match `[a-zA-Z0-9_.]`. That is, I want to add `.` to the character class. Is this possible?

I need to modify `\w` because I want a number of modules (e.g. [`Getopt::Long`](http://metacpan.org/module/Getopt::Long)) to see things like "foo.bar" as a valid word.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Why not use `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*`?

Comment: As [mbethke](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33054508/622310) has described, this is a very ugly hacky thing to want to do. Perhaps if you explained the problem you are trying to solve we could help you better?

Comment: One example, as stated in the question, is to make `Getopt::Long` to recognize `foo.bar` as a valid option specification.

Comment: @KevinVW: Yes, but why do you want to do *that*? The option spec is purely local to the Perl program and doesn't need to match anything externally

Comment: Talk to the author; they might be willing to add `.` for you

Comment: @Borodin, the option specs are actually taken from an external source ( a remote DB). Also my interface has to match other applications that do accept `.` has a word char.

Comment: @KevinVW: Thank you for your explanation. I don't think it's important how the parameters are named in the original database, but I can see that there may be little room for manoeuvre if a precedent has been set. How do the other similar applications process their command line? If you are always expecting something simple like `a.b=1 c.d=2` then it is a bad choice to use an extensive module like `Getopt::Long` that does far more than you need and also needs modifying to make it fit

Comment: @Borodin: I appreciate your input, but this is a complex system with a long history and many moving parts. I just wanted the answer to my original question which if possible would simplify things. Getopt:Long et al. are simple enough that I don't mind just reproducing them internally to fit my needs. In the end I made Getopt::Long configurable to use a custom `\p{IsWord}` for parsing specs while retaining default behavior otherwise.

Comment: @KevinVW: Likewise, I appreciate your willingness to explain your circumstances. But there are too many Stack Overflow questions that ask about making a mechanism work instead of how to achieve a purpose. It would be remiss of me to simply answer your question as it stands without establishing that you have chosen a good solution in the first place. That said, you do seem to know what you're doing, and coding a custom Unicode property is much nicer than your original proposition. I hope it works for you, but do remember to honour the GNU Public License which is almost certainly applicable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all
a) untested
b) extremely nasty
c) inconvenient
so it should rather be a comment, alas I can't write any yet.

I see only two possibilities:

- Write a custom locale
  The \w class uses `LC_CTYPE` under `use locale` to determine what characters are considered "word characters". The perllocale manpage mentions as a security aspect that

  > Regular expression checks for safe file names or mail addresses using "\w" may be spoofed by an "LC_CTYPE" locale that claims that characters such as ">" and "|" are alphanumeric.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to do this (at least on Unixish OSes, no idea about Windows) without installing system-global configuration. [Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21316/how-can-i-customize-a-system-locale) has a thread about that.

- Monkey-patch the required functions. This opens a different can of worms if you don't know the respective versions of the modules to patch that users might have (you could some with your script though).

All in all, better think twice about doing stuff like that, it's just too likely that it will break other parts of the system and in any case it makes maintenance a nightmare.

Comment: *"Monkey-patch the required functions"* As far as I know that would require the Perl interpreter to be edited and rebuilt

Comment: @Borodin: Sorry, I wasn't clear about that -- I meant the functions in`Getopt::Long` and the like that the OP wants to behave differently by way of the changed `\w`.

Comment: I ended up just making local copies of the modules in the lib directory of my project and patching those. This way I can be sure my patched versions are used. There ended up only being a handful of modules needed my patch.

Answer (score 6):

There's no way to change the meaning of predefined character classes. However you can build your own by using `[\w.]`

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to say until I scrolled upon your post.